# web2py: Dynamically defined session variables

Tags: web2py

Hello web2py community!

I'm currently developing a control mechanism between components all operating on common data cluster named *model* which is identified by *model_id*. The communication between the components is realized via session variables.

But since the user should have the option to operate on several models in parallel, I need to differentiate the session variables used for each model.

For this purpose I want to complement the different session variables by the *model_id* as unique identifier.

To read such a session variable is the easy part, e.g.

```
current_action = eval('session.manage_action_%s' % model_id)
```

But writing a new value to that session variable doesn't work. My solution until now is as follows:

```
vars()['session.manage_action_%s' % model_id] = new_action
```

This only produces *a local variable* session.manage_action_5 (or whatever value of *model_id*). But it's not a real, reusable and readable session variable.

Thus my question is:

***How can I generate a dynamically defined session variable depending on a variable value read on runtime?***

Thanks for any support in advance, since it would be great to have a solution for that ...

Best regards,
Clemens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `session` object is a dictionary-like object, so you can use dictionary syntax for dynamically generated keys:

```
session['manage_action_%s' % model_id] = new_action
current_action = session['manage_action_%s' % model_id]
```

or:

```
session.update(**{'manage_action_%s' % model_id: new_action})
current_action = session.get('manage_action_%s' % model_id)
```

Comment: As always your answer is the solution ... thanks a lot, Anthony!